# Make classes in php

Tags: php, class

I am beginning to make classes in php. I have make a reference to my class, but I have the following error:

> **Fatal error**: Class 'NumberCode' not found in **C:\...\MasterMind.php** on line **14**

I have made this code:

```
<?php

class NumberCode
{
    public $Code;

    function __construct()
    {
        print "ok";
    }

    function makeCode()
    {
        $counter = 1;

        while ($counter < 5)
        {
            $this->Code = $this->Code . rand(1, 6);
            print "ok";
            $counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the reference:

```
<?php
    $combination = new NumberCode();
    $combination -> makeCode();
    $code = $combination -> Code;
    print $code
?>
```

I have try to print some lines code and I have used Fiddler.

Comment: Is this code in the same file?

Comment: btw, you missed `$counter+=1;` in WHILE

Comment: As you're learning, a suggestion for you: Use `camelCase` for method names and `PascalCase` for class names.

Comment: Listen to @MarcioSimao. I was about to say the same.

Comment: No, the class is not in the same file. I have make a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file that uses your class needs to include the file that defines your class. You typically do this with a [`require`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) or [`require_once`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) statement.

```
<?php

require_once('path_to_class_file.php');

$combination = new NumberCode();
$combination -> MakeCode();
$code = $combination -> Code;
print $code
?>
```